# How to prevent editing on mac resulting in whole file appearing as deleted and added lines?

Tags: git

I recently started coding on a mac. I checked out my source from my repo at github, made changes and pushed from a mac and suddenly the whole file appears as deleted and added lines. I suspect this is because of newline character differences.

I used to develop on ubuntu and prior to that on Windows.

How can I avoid this with future commits, is there any conversion that needs to be done to the files before committing to get the actual diff to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git provides options to deal with newline issues. Here's a chapter on configuration from Git Book (known also as Pro Git), which is a terrific resource by the way. I recommend reading the whole thing.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace

Answer (score 3):

Should be fine now that you have synced with your repo.
New files will be correct. And if you pushed and pulled then you should have the same code on both sides.

P.S great avatar.

Comment: +1 For having talked to each other the night before about what avatar you would wear today.

Comment: I haven't updated all the files, the ones that I modify are all appearing as all deleted, all added.

Comment: Context for anyone reading this in the futures. I had stewie as my gravar as did earlonrais.

Answer (score 2):

You can see if your editor has an option to preserve the file's line endings.  For example, Xcode has “Default line endings” and “Convert existing files on save” options in its Preferences > Text Editing > Editing preferences.

Git has various configuration options that affect line endings.  Github has a help page about these options: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings